# Editing data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i need help with haskell i'm kinda confused.

I have custom types/Data like this:

```
type Name         = String 
type LastName     = String
type Mail         = String
type FullName     = (LastName, Name)

data Person       = Person Mail FullName deriving (Show, Read)
type Contact      = (FullName,Mail)
type MailAccount = (Person,[Contact])
```

Let's assume that mail account is stored in a data_base , what i want from now is update the list of contact and i don't know how to do it  using this signature:

```
updateContact :: Mail -> LastName -> Name ->MailAccount -> IO MailAccount
```

I tried with this :

```
updateContact l n m macc = do
           x <- createPerson l n m
           return $ mailAccountUpdate macc x
```

I created these three function:

```
 --return my list of contacts
  contacts:: MailAccount->[Contact]
  contacts (_,_,con) = con

  createPerson l n m = do
       return (Person m (l,n))

  mailAccountUpdate acc x = do 
       return (x:contact acc)
```

1. My problem is that thes code won't work  because return `$ mailAccountUpdate macc x` retruns a list and not an IO MailAccount.
2. I'm not skilled enough to play with the `functors` and `fmap` yet.
3. I want a way to update my list of contact in the mail account , meaning i want a way to access and edit this data and override it with the updated list.
4. I have to respect the signature , so i tried to play with the logic in the terminal, so i tried a few things so my question is  :

Is there a way to edit the data directly like OOP `ex : MailAccount.contact()` ? if not how can i create a function that can do the work.

Is there a way to have for example two mailAccount with the same type and code it to do the equivalent of this in the ghci terminal :

```
mail1 = mail2
```

This will override the data in mail1 with the data from mail2. but i dont know how to code it in haskell with data type.

Thank you everyone in advance for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by "a data_base"? What exactly is `updateContact` supposed to do? Just add a new entry to the list of contacts in a MailAccount?

Comment: Why are you using IO everywhere? If a function does not need to have side effects, don't use IO. `createPerson l n m = Person m (l,n)` is better. Avoid `do` if not using monads. Don't use `return` if not working with monads. You are thinking about imperative code and trying to shoehorn it into Haskell, but that won't work.

Comment: @melpomene yes just add new entry and by data base  i mean that mail account is a stored variable.

Comment: @chi ok i see , thanks for the advice

Comment: `Person` and `Contact` are isomorphic, it isn't quite clear why you need `MailAccount` with the same data twice. Of course in real life a person may have more than one mail address so `Person Mail FullName` is hardly an adequate representation of a person. I suspect you need to take this into account. Names are also not unique, so identifying a person with their name is not realistic. Not speaking of the `FullName  = (LastName, Name)` equation which holds in the fantasy world of CS101 exercises but not elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you contacts function. It should be

```
contacts (_,x) = x
```

MailAccount is a tuple, with first element as person and second as contact. So it cannot be (*,*,x) but should be (_,x).

The below updatecontact definition is working fine.

```
updateContact l n m macc = let myP = Person l (n,m) 
                               newMacc = (myP,((n,m),l):contacts macc) 
                           in return newMacc
```

I agree with others that there is no need for using IO in definition. The error would have been understood easily without IO.

Answer (score 2):

There is a neater version of this but I'm doing like this so it can be more understanding:

```
type Name     = String
type LastName = String
type Mail     = String
type Id       = Int
type FullName = (LastName, Name)
type Contact  = (Id, FullName)

data Person =
  Person Mail FullName [Contact]
  deriving (Show, Read)

updatePersonContact :: Person -> FullName -> Id -> Person
updatePersonContact (Person m fn contacts) newfullName id =
    Person m fn (updateContact id newfullName contacts)

updateContact :: Id -> FullName -> [Contact] -> [Contact]
updateContact id newfullName contacts =
  map (\(i, fn) ->
         if i == id
         then (i, newfullName)
         else (i, fn)) contacts

person1 :: Person
person1 = Person "email@me.com"("last","first")
            [(1,("last1","first1")), (2,("last2","first2"))]
```

then using it you would:

```
> updatePersonContact person1 ("NEW","NEWW") 2
-- Person "email@me.com" ("last","first") [(1,("last1","first1")),(2,("NEW","NEWW"))]
```

We've update `Person` to have a list of `[Contact]` so now contacts are attached to a person. Each `Contact` now has an `Id` that we can use for getting to the right contact.

You can deconstruct your types in the input like so `updatePersonContact (Person m fn contacts)` so now we can use all the bits we need to reconstruct our person.
With `m fn` we give them straight back as those don't need changing. But we're interested in `contacts` so we pass it to this function `updateContact id newfullName contacts`.

In `updateContact` as inputs we have an `Id`, `FullName` and list of `[Contact]`.
the way to loop over a list is to use `map` so here we are using map to go through our list of contacts one by one. `map () contacts`

the `()` needs to be a function from `a -> b` and our `a` when it loops the first time is `(1,("last1","first1")` so as you can see it has 2 values which we deal with by having `\(i, fn) ->`.
So `i == 1` and `fn == ("last1","first1")`. These would update on every iteration of the list like any loop.

The next part we check if `i == id` and if it does then that's the contact we want to update so we return `(i, newfullName)` which is our new full name originally passed into `updatePersonContact`. If `i` doesn't match `id` then let's just leave those values alone and return them as they came.

`map` is a functor so as you might see it's not that bad you might need to do a bit more reading on it to get a better understanding. :)

In Haskell lists are immutable which means every time you are given a list you must return a brand new list.

Comment: I apreciate the time you to to explain it to, sadly i can't change the type and signature or obviously i would have gone for and easier way : `updateContact :: Mail -> LastName -> Name ->MailAccount -> IO MailAccount` and `type MailAccount`